# Give a CSS styled div a "border-left-image"

Tags: css

Just trying to give the main content div on a site a border on the left and right side of the div. Rather than have separate divs for each border, I thought to use the `border-left-image` capability in CSS3 to make it happen. My code is as follows:

```
#content {
    background-color: #7FC3F4;
    height: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    border-left-width: 30px;
    border-left-image: url(../images/border_left_gradient.png);
    border-right-width: 30px;
    border-right-image: url(../images/border_right_gradient.png);
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Of all the Google searches I've done, I have to yet to come up with an explanation as to why this code isn't valid. Some results return numeric values to be placed after the url, however regardless of what combination of numbers I try, no dice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Like @SpliFF says, your urls should probably be ../images/border_etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`border-image` is [now supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) in all the major browsers (2014-05-22)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yas34/655/) with a single `border-left-image`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yas34/656/) with different left and right images.

The demos now need a minimum of Chrome 15, Safari 6, Firefox 15, IE 11 or Opera 15.

It is **not actually possible** to do this with separate image files, but you can *slice* a single image on the left and right. See the [`border-image` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) on MDN which shows some good examples or [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) for a comprehensive summary of how the other slicing options work.

*Note:* if you need earlier browser support please ask as a previous version of my answer did work with Chrome 12, Safari 5.0.3, Firefox 4 and Opera 10 but I have updated it now that new browsers support prefix-free CSS3.

*Edit:* Firefox now requires an additional property setting - `border-style: solid` (see [CSS - New Firefox-release doesn't show Border-Image anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295565/css-new-firefox-release-doesnt-show-border-image-anymore))

Comment: hey andyb! thanks for going to all that trouble to make that demo for me! however, when I pull that link up in Safari 5.0.3 and chrome 10.0.648.204 the Yoda still doesn't show. I captured a screen shot available here of what shows up on my screen. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13226833/Screen%20shot%202011-04-05%20at%202.42.51%20PM.png

Is it my computer? Is it broken?

Comment: Hmmm, it's definitely working on Chrome 12 for me (that's the version on the Chrome dev channel) but for some reason is not showing up on Safari 5.0.3 for me either. Should have checked that I guess! I'll look into it as it **should** work according to caniuse.com

Comment: Added an updated demo to the answer. I was not fully aware of the **very** different versions of this rule for different browsers.

Comment: Hey, so I copied and pasted your code and got the Yoda to work as it should. However, I'm using different images for the left side of the div and the right side of the div. What would need to get adjusted so that say Yoda could be on the left and Luke could be on the right?

Comment: Yes it is not very well supported or even fully implemented. The [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=497995) for the revised CSS3 spec (and `border-image-slice`) for example is still at status=NEW. Looks like the shorthand `border-image` is your best bet for now (please see the updated demo if you haven't already).

Comment: Oooo, I like a challenge! You will need to splice your left and right images together (. So in my demo for example, you will need a 100x50px image. Just replace the url and it will work. Also see updated demo in answer above :-)

Comment: Got it! Thanks andyb for all your help!

Comment: Great! If you are happy with a solution it is good practice to up-vote and/or accept and answer, otherwise other users will not know it has been solved.

Comment: my bad, thanks for the orientation. soon as I get some more stackoverflow cred, i'll up vote this puppy.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but question appears to have been regarding left and right borders individually, which none of your demos consider. Is this not really a thing?

Comment: @Michael thanks, I have updated the demos for newer CSS3 compliant browsers showing which show a different image for left and right border (although it is not really separate image files).

Comment: @Matrix thanks for pointing this out. For some reason, Firefox requires `border-style: solid;` as well - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295565/css-new-firefox-release-doesnt-show-border-image-anymore

Answer (score 3):

Good solution : Chrome AND Firefox compatibility :

http://jsfiddle.net/Yas34/954/

missing `border-style: solid` to current "good answer"

Answer (score 0):

For one your url is bogus (..images?). for a second have you checked your browser supports the property? last I checked, which wasn't that long ago, nobody supported it (well maybe webkit nightlies).

Comment: Also, it is just IE that doesn't support it… Check http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image @OP, it _is_ probably the url you use for your images.

Comment: hey, ya'll are right. it is a bogus url and should read "(../images/border_left_gradient.png)" Turns out I just pasted the inaccurate code into my question (I've even also copied the images to the root folder so the string would read "url(border_left_gradient.png)" to no avail). However, even though I changed the URL, it still won't display a border image. I too thought it was just an issue of browsers not supporting it, but the latest builds of Chrome and FireFox say they should. Which brings me back to square one.