# border image unknown property?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Give a CSS styled div a “border-left-image”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541336/give-a-css-styled-div-a-border-left-image)

Im trying to put a border on a div, to the left and to the right of the div.

HTML:

```
 <div id="containerscontainer"><div>
```

CSS:

```
#containerscontainer {
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#000;       
    border-left-image:url('/gfx/bkshadleft.png');
    border-right-image:url('/gfx/bkshadright.png');
}
```

[image]
[image]

but for some reason in chrome i can see im getting error unknown property name? why is this? am i not doing it right?

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/8dX7R/3/

Comment: Huh? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541336/give-a-css-styled-div-a-border-left-image

Comment: You could define the border image for all borders and then set `border-width` for the top and bottom to be 0: `border-width: 0 10px;`?

Comment: the border has to be different on each side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work in Chrome, you need to name the style:

-webkit-border-left-image

See this post: [Give a CSS styled div a "border-left-image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541336/give-a-css-styled-div-a-border-left-image)

Comment: i want it to work in all browsers

Comment: also i have tried that see my example please

Comment: so just add both styles to your css, it will use the right one depending on browser ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I feel like the syntax might be off, or the images aren't the right dimensions and the borders are off. I'd recommend using a website like this to generate the images:

http://border-image.com/

And also, I see no border images in your Fiddle.

Comment: yeh thats the issue the borders arent appearing