# CSS - New Firefox-release doesn't show Border-Image anymore

Tags: html, css, firefox

After the Firefox update the Border Image doesn't show up anymore at all? 
You might have defined somthing like this:

```
border-width:30px;
-moz-border-image: url('border.png') 64 64 64 64 stretch stretch;
   -webkit-border-image: url('border.png') 64 64 64 64 stretch stretch;
   -o-border-image: url('border.png') 64 64 64 64 stretch stretch;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had to look around for a bit to realize it's a Firefox Problem. First I thought AdBlock might have just blocked it for some reason. It's actually a change Mozilla did to their CSS Interpretation. You now MUST add this property underneath it for it to work:

```
border-style:solid;
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: You could obviously help yourself: +1

Comment: The reason the change was made is that the spec was changed to require that behavior, for what it's worth.

Comment: you helped me, I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As per the specifications, Firefox requires `border-image-width` to be set.

Just include the above property.

Here, `border-style` will correct the issue, but to be more logical and related, its better to use `border-image-width` instead of `border-style` or `border-width` sometimes.

Comment: @dardub please check the below link!

http://codepen.io/Yeswanth-JG/pen/JflBk (its working in firefox too!)

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding:

```
border: 15px solid transparent;
```

Where 15px is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Add `fill`:

```
-webkit-border-image: url(<%= asset_path('wxskvip_head_frame.png') %>) 6 fill stretch;
```