# border-image is not working

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox isn't showing CSS `border-image`. Other browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera) are showing this without Problems.

I have following code:

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
    header here
</div><!-- headerwrapper -->

<div id="mainwrapper">
    maincontent here
</div><!-- mainwrapper -->
```

and this CSS:

```
#headerwrapper {
    border-bottom-width: 15px;
    border-image: url(images/zickzack-white.png) 15 0 repeat;
    border-image-outset: 7px;
}
#mainwrapper {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    background-size: 100px 200px;
    padding: 20px 0 200px;
}
```

[This picture shows result in Chrome (upper part) and Firefox (lower part)](http://s14.directupload.net/images/140702/fy5ui9d3.jpg)

Can someone please help?

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295565/css-new-firefox-release-doesnt-show-border-image-anymore

Can you try adding border-style:solid;?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838289/using-border-image-with-slice-in-ie11 it was indeed the border-style problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 26px 27px 27px;
-moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 26 26 27 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 26 26 27 27 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 26 26 27 27 repeat;
border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 26 26 27 27 fill repeat;
```

Comment: The important part here is the `border-style: solid`, which is required by the spec.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla Firefox 15+ supports "border-image".

Mozilla Firefox 3.5+ supports "-moz-border-image".

You can use the following generator: http://border-image.com
It might help writing the CSS code for "border-image".

You can try the following code:

```
#headerwrapper {    
    border-style: solid; border-width: 27px; -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat; 
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat; 
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 repeat; 
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 27 fill repeat;
}
```