# Don't understand why Firefox is displaying white background behind my text

Tags: firefox, css

A Firefox change broke some of my background/border images. See this issue for more details: [CSS - New Firefox-release doesn't show Border-Image anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295565/css-new-firefox-release-doesnt-show-border-image-anymore). When I fixed this issue by adding `border-style: solid` my text now displays a white/gray background behind it. Any idea why this might be happening. See my image on Chrome (how it is supposed to look) and then on Firefox.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nirodhasoftware/offuhxao/1/

Comment: Just added one, @SureshPonnukalai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw a background too.
From pseudo or from element itself :2 examples to tune to your needs.

**[pseudo:](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/gcavhn20/)**

```
background:#5099D6;
background-clip:padding-box;
```

**[element:](http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/gcavhn20/1/)**

```
background:url(http://www.rwe-uk.com/static/ichat_with_css3/speech_bubble_left_2.png) center / 300% 150%;
background-clip:content-box;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked perfectly. Why does Firefox require this fix? It didn't used to.

Comment: @Doug, as you noticed, it is a failure/bug of Firefox, you can only patch it as you need a background